# Using angular directive within md-virtual-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to implement Angular Material's Virtual Repeat with a custom directive for the list items, and I'm having issues binding scope attrs to the directive.

Here's what I have:

**HTML**

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
  <div md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.dynamicItems">
    <foo bar="item"></foo>
  </div>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

**JS**

```
myApp.directive("foo", function(){
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
        bar: "="
      },
      template: "<span>{{baz}}</span>",
      link: function(scope){
        scope.baz = "new " + scope.bar; 
      }
    }
```

**Issue**

The items in the virtual scrolling section seem to be there, but their value is showing as `new undefined`, when I'm expecting them to be *new 1*, *new 2*, and so on.

The strange thing is that some items do appear to show their values properly (namely, *new 11*, *new 12*, and sometimes *new 13*). Also, the issue gets solved if instead I replace my directive's template to `"<span>{{bar}}</span>"` which deems the directive's link function unnecessary. This leads me to think the problem is with the timing of the linking (would be my best guess).

Here's a link to the [corresponding CodePen snippet](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEKVRx) for more clarification.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved it - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/wWXqKx?editors=1010#0)

JS

```
  .directive("foo", function(){
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
        bar: "="
      },
      template: "<span>{{test()}}</span>",
      link: function(scope){
        scope.test = function () {
          if (angular.isDefined(scope.bar)) {
            return "new " + scope.bar;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```